# Will unknowingly eating haram affect my fasting and prayers for 40 days? If so how?

Tags: ramadan, sawm, food

I usually always check ingredients before I buy things, but it slipped my mind today when I bought a pack of mellows for the first time. I came home and had 2, and when I was on my third one realized I hadn't checked the ingredients, and saw that it had pork gelatine very clearly written in the ingredients. I tried vomiting, but nothing much came up.

How will it affect my sawm and ibaadat in the next 40 days?

Answer (score 1):

First of all I think we should not take the "40 days rule " literally. If yes then please provide the sources and your conclusion.

**And now the answer:**

God can forgive you instantly, and even more than that. He can forgive you before you act, for he is all knowing, merciful.

The scholars put together a simple guideline for us in regards to Tauba.
Tauba is the act of asking for forgiveness.

1. Regret what you did.
2. Intent not to do that again. In your case, try to understand how this could have happened and find a solution to prevent.
3. Ask God for forgiveness.

And remember: Abraham sinned, asked for forgiveness and God forgave. Abraham sinned again, asked for forgiveness and God forgave again. Abraham sinned again, asked for forgiveness and God forgave again.
Abraham was sincere, honest and God fearing.

Answer (score 0):

If you ate Haram unknowingly be through some individual or some product you are not to blame (unless it really calls for it) let me elaborate.

1. If you eat Haram unknowingly in a Muslim gathering the one who brought the food is to blame for what and how much the people ate from it.
2. In a Non-Muslim gathering just politely ask the one who made the food (you can give a pretext of allergies if the people there are not very sympathetic with Muslim though being honest at all times is better)
3. If you ate haram i don't know of any laws that forces you to throw it up.

You should by all means ask Allah (swt) forgiveness for your shortcoming. Because indeed eating Haram is a sin but Allah (swt) is always ready to forgive sins even if it were to reach the highest sky.

Also you should throw in the garbage the leftover food and don't give it away (even to non-Muslim).

Some reference.

> http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=84660
>
> http://islamqa.info/en/20843